# Add inline Javascripts on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, footer, adblock, inline-scripting

I want to add inline Javascript on footer of my wordpress site. I know we can add inline Javascript using [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). From my understanding from Codex tutorial, we have to register and enqueue scripts and then using wp_add_inline_script.

Let say I:

1. Register **ScriptA.js** using wp_register_script.
2. Enqueue **ScriptA.js** using wp_enqueue_script.
3. Add inline **ScriptB.js** using wp_add_inline_script with handle ScriptA.js.

**My Question:**

1. As far as I can remember, Adblock Plus (Web browser ext) or similar can block external **.js**. If my ScriptA.js being blocked by Adblock Plus, will my ScriptB.js loaded?
2. IF it is blocked, is there any other proper way I can add inline Javascripts? The only I can think is simply print (echo) it using wp_footer hook.

**Reason using inline Javascripts**: To prevent Adblock user from blocking my Ads script. Because Adblock Plus cannot block inline script as said by their Dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** This is not my own answer. I simply copy paste this answer from Wordpress support forum. Credit goes to [@bcworkz](https://wordpress.org/support/users/bcworkz/) (Wordpress moderator/developer).

> The inline script is still output even if the enqueued file request is
>   blocked. AFAIK anyway, not verified, but I’m pretty sure this is the
>   case. The inline output cannot know the enqueued request was blocked,
>   the block is external to the server. Of course, the added inline
>   cannot be dependent on the blocked enqueued script if it is to work
>   correctly. Your ad content would need to be part of the inline script,
>   any external requests can still be blocked.
>
> While AdBlock cannot block inline script, it can remove specific DOM
>   elements. The key is to avoid having any consistent identifiers in
>   your ad elements.